# Second IP for VPS on VmWare ESXI?

Tags: vmware-esxi, ip, vps, nic, mac-address

I bought a VPS Server run on vmware ESXI and this server just had one IP; Now I decided to ask from the reseller to give me another IP; He says in order to do that he have to remove my account and create a new one with 2 network cards (nic). (this will lose all the data I have on the server)

Now i have 2 question?

1. I there a way that, he add a new network card without removing my account and creating new one?
2. If not; I found out i can set a new IP address on my ONE network card (nic) in this way **eth0:0**. In this scenario could i just give an IP and run with it or the reseller has to do something on his part too? if yes **WHAT IS IT that he must do?**

Comment: Sounds like these questions should be directed at your provider

Answer (score 1):

This depends completely on the provider's network configuration.

A virtual NIC can be easily added attached to any port group available on the host the VM's running on (while the VM's running), so I doubt that's what the provider's stuck on.  (If that *is* what they're stuck on, find a new provider immediately, as that's very much a "vSphere 101" concept.)

It's a bit of a stretch to come up with good reasons that the destruction of the VM would be necessary, but, maybe the new IP would need to be on a different network which isn't available on the host/cluster it's currently on?

I'd say try to get more details on why this is needed.  If they're just going to rebuild the VM in the same place with one extra vNIC on a new port group.. that's not a good thing.

Comment: As far as I can get it out of them; it is on the same place with extra vNIC; but he tells me every IP needs a MAC too and that is why he wants to remove and create the account.

Comment: AS of now; I have to be were I am because my contract isn't up yet but; any info that i can get I will pass it on to them ( Ticket them) and they will follow my lead. (I don't now their setup so i can't account for them being 101). anyway If you or anyone else could get more clues either on case 1 or 2 i will follow.

Comment: @r004 Well, the basic premise of "every IP needs a MAC" is not correct - ARP has no problem with multiple IPs resolving to the same MAC address.  If you can get them to just give you the new IP, then you should be able to just configure it on your interface within the OS and be good to go without changes to the VM.  Otherwise, tell them this: Right click the VM in the vSphere client, Edit Settings, click the "Add" button above the hardware list, select Ethernet Adapter and click Next, default adapter type is probably fine and select the right port group, next and finish.